# Disable gzip compression on Openshift (HTTPD cartridge)

Tags: apache, gzip, openshift

I made a apache web server cartridge which only contains httpd,so I can do lots of customization.However I can't disalbe gzip!(Because I use URLLoader to load swf in my flash,and the gzip causes some problems.)

1. I modify httpd.conf to ask httpd not load mod_deflate at all by
    '#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so'.

2. I also considered the haproxy.cfg,but because the haproxy version is 1.4, it doesn't support compression algo identity at all.

I have read this FAQ:Disable gzip compression on Openshift (php cartridge),someone answerd that because of OpenShift proxy it's impossible to disable gzip.Does OpenShift proxy means haproxy?And I really want to know if there is anyway to stop gzip for any kind of cartridge hosting on OpenShift?